# How can I move just one of many shapes inside canvas by 50 pixels;

Tags: javascript

I have a project to do and I cannot do it until I understand how moving object inside canvas work. 
I need to move one of the objects below by 50pixels to right.
Anyone willing to help me is greatly appreciated. 
Meanwhile thank you very much in advance for your help or suggestions.

function canvasOneShape() {

```
//refers to the html canvasone id
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvasOne");
this.canvasOne.width = 945;
this.canvasOne.height = 650;
// draws the canvas in 2d
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
// Set the fill colour to blue.
ctx.fillStyle = "blue"; //used like this instead of rgb due personal preference:)
// Create a filled rectangle at co-ordinates (10,10)
// with height and width set to 100.
ctx.fillRect(10, 10, 250, 330); //

// Here I draw the square
// Set the canvas up for drawing in 2D.
// Set the fill colour to blue.
ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(244, 244, 189,.5)";
ctx.fillRect(10, 50, 330, 250);

//draw my first circle
var midXone = canvas.width / 2;     //x location
var midXtwo = canvas.height / 2;    //y location
var radius = 60;                    //circle radius

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(midXone, midXtwo, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
ctx.fillStyle ="rgba(89, 192, 227,.4)";
ctx.fill();
ctx.lineWidth = 5;
ctx.strokeStyle = '#003300';
ctx.stroke();

//draw the second circle
var midX = canvas.width / 2.35;     //x location
var midY = canvas.height / 2.35;    //y location
var radius = 50;                    //circle radius
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(midX, midY, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
ctx.fillStyle ="rgba(66, 244, 89,.4)";
ctx.fill();
ctx.lineWidth = 5;
ctx.strokeStyle ="rgba(255, 244, 9,.4)";
ctx.stroke();

//draw Square with circle inside
//square
ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(222, 33, 51)";
ctx.fillRect(550, 20, 300, 300);
//circle

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(700, 170, 150, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
ctx.fillStyle ="rgba(66, 244, 89,.4)";
ctx.fill();
ctx.lineWidth = 1;
ctx.strokeStyle = '#f44242';
ctx.stroke();

//The Pacman object

    var radius = 100;                   //circle radius
    var x = 100;
    var y = 500;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(120, 500, radius, 1.85 * Math.PI, .15 * Math.PI, true);

    //Draw mouth
    ctx.lineTo(120, 500);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(255, 255, 0)";
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.lineWidth = 5;
    ctx.strokeStyle = 'rgb(0,0,0)';
    ctx.stroke();

    //draw eye
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(x + 40, y - 40, 10, 0 * Math.PI, 2 * Math.PI, true);
    ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(0,0,0)";
    ctx.fill();
```

}

Comment: As I understand it, canvas is like a painting canvas - once it's there, you're stuck with it.  Sometimes there's something like a "backing store" that's a copy of the canvas at a particular state ... so you would copy that saved version, then draw your circle again, but this time moved by 50px

Answer (score 0):

there are no layers or objects on a canvas(it's just a single layer of pixels), so, if you draw something, you overwrite what's underneath it. to move something to the right, you will need to have a function to draw everything behind it, and then variables to store the location (x and y) of the objects you want to move. 
then, to move it, you clear the canvas with
 `ctx.clearRect(0, 0,width of canvas, height height of canvas);`, 
call the background function to draw everything behind it again, and the redraw your object in a different location.

Comment: please check this and press the up button if you like my answer!